# sockaddr_in causing segfault?

Tags: c, sockets, include

Working on creating a server/client system in C right now, and I'm having a little trouble with the client part. From what I've seen, I need to use sockaddr_in so I can connect to the server. However, I've been getting a segfault every time. I believe that sockaddr_in has something to do with it, as commenting it and it's references later in the program fixes the segfault.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int Csock;
int con;
char *data = 0;
char buf[101] = "";
struct sockaddr_in addr;

Csock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(3435);

con = connect(Csock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));

write(con, "Text", sizeof("Text"));
*data = read(con, buf, 100);
puts(data);
return 0;
}
```

sadly, I am rather new to C, so that's as much as I can figure... can anyone tell me a way to go about eliminating the segfault?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick comment:

data is a pointer to char which does not point to an allocated memory, so:

```
*data = read(con, buf, 100);
```

is invalid! You cannot dereference a NULL pointer.

Also, read returns `ssize_t`, and not a char, so perhaps:

```
ssize_t nread = read(con, buf, 100);
```

and then print out the nread with `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

One immediately-apparent thing that's wrong is taking `sizeof &addr` when you mean `sizeof addr`. Also you never set the address you want to connect to, only the port. On most systems neither of these errors would cause a crash, but they will keep the program from working.

Also it's advisable never to setup `sockaddr` structures directly, but instead use `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: As I didn't have time to write a proper answer, Ill add some of the errors here: the `struct sockaddr_in addr;` is not initialized, most importantly the ip address to connect to is not set. `*data = read(con, buf, 100);` dereferences a NULL pointer, and the types arn't the same either. `connect/write/read` should be checked for errors (and likely how much they actually read or wrote as well)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think, lies with your connect statement.  You need

```
con = connect(Csock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

sizeof() returns the size of the object.  I don't offhand know what the size of the addr structure is, but the statement sizeof(&addr) will return 4 (assuming 32 bit system) and I'm quite sure that the size of the addr structure is > 4 bytes.

The & is the reference operator (or address of) and gives you the address of a particular structure.  Address (in 32 bit systems) are 4 bytes.  Usually the types of functions (like the connect function) want the actual size of the structure.  This is often done for backwards compatibility purposes so that if the size of the structure changes in some future version of the SDK or library, older code doesn't need to change in order to work with the newer libraries.

Comment: er, actually, I forgot to change that back. I added the & just to see what would occur (nothing) and I guess I didn't remove it before posting here. Even without the & it still causes a segfault

Comment: Okay, well, the other problem is with the line *data = read(...) (and/or the next line) read() returns the number of bytes read off of the socket - it doesn't return the data read.  The data off the socket is returned in "buf".  You probably want something like int num_read = read( con, buf, 100 );  puts(buf);  Really though, you should check num_read to make sure it's >0 to make sure you read data off of the socket.  And you need to make sure what you read is NULL terminated if you are going to print it

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware that the read function returned the bytes of data! That helps quite a bit, thanks!

Comment: @OP: programming by trial and error is a technique you should try to eliminate from your mental toolbox.